# Get store url magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to get the store url in Magento 2. I follow this tutorial and other tutorials have the same answer as well

https://www.rootways.com/blog/magento-2-get-base-url-in-phtml-file

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 

$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$store = $storeManager->getStore();
echo $store->getBaseUrl();
```

The `getStore` function will return `StoreInterface`. However, I can see that there is NO `getBaseUrl` function in the StoreInterface

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Store\Api\Data;

/**
 * Store interface
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
interface StoreInterface extends \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId();

    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setId($id);

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCode();

    /**
     * @param string $code
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCode($code);

    /**
     * Retrieve store name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName();

    /**
     * Set store name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setName($name);

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getWebsiteId();

    /**
     * @param int $websiteId
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setWebsiteId($websiteId);

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getStoreGroupId();

    /**
     * @param int $isActive
     * @return $this
     * @since 101.0.0
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive);

    /**
     * @return int
     * @since 101.0.0
     */
    public function getIsActive();

    /**
     * @param int $storeGroupId
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setStoreGroupId($storeGroupId);

    /**
     * Retrieve existing extension attributes object or create a new one.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreExtensionInterface|null
     */
    public function getExtensionAttributes();

    /**
     * Set an extension attributes object.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setExtensionAttributes(
        \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes
    );
}
```

How can I get the store name and store URL in Magento2?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Test.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_storeManager;    
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    
    /**
     * Get store identifier
     *
     * @return  int
     */
    public function getStoreId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    }
    
    /**
     * Get website identifier
     *
     * @return string|int|null
     */
    public function getWebsiteId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
    }
    
    /**
     * Get Store code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStoreCode()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
    }
    
    /**
     * Get Store name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStoreName()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getName();
    }
    
    /**
     * Get current url for store
     *
     * @param bool|string $fromStore Include/Exclude from_store parameter from URL
     * @return string     
     */
    public function getStoreUrl($fromStore = true)
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentUrl($fromStore);
    }
    
    /**
     * Check if store is active
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isStoreActive()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->isActive();
    }
}
?>
```

**now in your .phtml file**

```
echo $block->getStoreId() . '<br />';
echo $block->getStoreCode() . '<br />';
echo $block->getWebsiteId() . '<br />';
echo $block->getStoreName() . '<br />';
echo $block->getStoreUrl() . '<br />';
echo $block->isStoreActive() . '<br />';
```

**comment out the stuff which you dont need**

**hope this helps!**

Comment: is the working for you?